# Significance of rays in Thin film Interference

Tags: optics, interference

Why is thin film interference always more significant for reflected rays only?what happens in case of refracted rays?

Comment: I am waiting for a nice answer too. But refraction does not change phase

Comment: Yes you say right

Comment: But I would like to have it more clear in mind. I ll perhaps try to sketch it...